# How to apply a function over multiple number of .csv file?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, correlation

I have a huge number of csv files that are named with the follwing structure: 
df_climate_a_subset_b (a ranges from 1:12 and b ranges from 1:1000). Each file looks like this:

```
names<- c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11")
value1 <- c(2,3.1,4.5,1,6.5,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,4,12.3) 
value2 <- c(2.5,3.1,4.5,2,12,7.1,8.5,10,10.1,17.8,12.3) 
value3 <- c(2,3.1,2,5.1,12,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,17.8,12.3) 
value4 <- c(1,3.1,4.5,5.1,12,7.1,8.5,1,10.1,17.8,12.3) 

df_climate_1_subset_1 <- data.frame(names,value1,value2,value3,value4)
```

I also have a single file containing #b columns.

```
names<- c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11")
subset1 <- c(5.5,3,4,1,6,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,4,12.3) 
subset2 <- c(2.5,3.1,4.5,2.5,12,7.1,8.5,10,10.1,17.8,12.3) 
subset3 <- c(1,1,1.1,8.5,9,10.1,1,1.5,3,2,4) 
subset4 <- c(1,3.1,4.5,0,12,7.1,0,1,10.1,17.8,12.3) 

subsets_temp <- data.frame(names,subset1,subset2,subset3,subset4)
```

I have had a hard time to figure out what is the efficient way to get the correlation between each climte for all subsets and the correponding column from
subsets_temp dataframe.

Best

Comment: How do you want to calculate the correlation for a single matching set of `subsets_temp` and `df_climate_1_subset_1`? What is the expected output?

Comment: Just to be sure. You have the column "names" and 1000 columns "subsetX" in your single file? How many columns "valueX" do you have in the other files (say K)? And for a given "df_climate_a_subset_b" file, you want a vector of correlation between the "valueX" columns with the specific "subsetb" column of your single file so that it's a vector of K values? So, the result would be a 12 x 1000 x K array?

Comment: right, column "names" and 1000 columns "subsetb" in my single file. I have four columns in the other file. I guess so, the results will be 12*1000*K correlation coefficients but I need to keep track of their climate, subset and K so I can plot them separately at the end. @F.Privé

Comment: I want the correlation coefficient  between each column of df_climate_1_subset_1 and the corresponding column of the subsets_temp. Of course this should be done for all df_climate__subset_ files...@ChiPak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a reproducible example:

```
# example of dataset
df_climate_1_subset_1 <- data.frame(
  names  = c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11"),
  value1 = c(2,3.1,4.5,1,6.5,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,4,12.3),
  value2 = c(2.5,3.1,4.5,2,12,7.1,8.5,10,10.1,17.8,12.3),
  value3 = c(2,3.1,2,5.1,12,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,17.8,12.3),
  value4 = c(1,3.1,4.5,5.1,12,7.1,8.5,1,10.1,17.8,12.3) 
)
# one df to compare with (100 subsets, not 1000)
subsets_temp <- data.frame(
  names   = c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11"),
  subset1 = c(5.5,3,4,1,6,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,4,12.3),
  subset2 = c(2.5,3.1,4.5,2.5,12,7.1,8.5,10,10.1,17.8,12.3), 
  subset3 = c(1,1,1.1,8.5,9,10.1,1,1.5,3,2,4),
  subset4 = c(1,3.1,4.5,0,12,7.1,0,1,10.1,17.8,12.3) 
)
for (i in 5:100) {
  subset <- paste0("subset", i)
  subsets_temp[[subset]] <- subsets_temp[["subset4"]]
}
# write some files to the disk (in dir tmp/)
for (a in 1:12) {
  for (b in 1:100) {
    filename <- paste("tmp/df_climate", a, "subset", b, sep = "_")
    write.csv(df_climate_1_subset_1, filename, row.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Solution:
I suppose that names are in the same order for all files.

```
library(foreach)

res <- foreach(a = 1:12) %:% 
  foreach(b = 1:100, .combine = "cbind") %do% {
    if (b == 1) print(a)
    filename <- paste("tmp/df_climate", a, "subset", b, sep = "_")
    df <- read.csv(filename)
    subset <- paste0("subset", b)
    cor(df[-1], subsets_temp[[subset]])
  }
```

This gives you a list of 12 elements (corresponding to each value of `a`). Each element is a matrix of 4 * 100.

At the beginning, I thought we would have to use parallelism (this is why that interested me) but it seems to be super fast so it's useless.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It can not read in the file thu! maybe we have to speify the .csv here?                                                                            filename <- paste("tmp/df_climate", a, "subset", b, sep = "_")
somehow? @F.Prive

Comment: Yeap you need to adapt the solution a little for your case. You could use `paste0("df_climate_", a, "subset_", b, ".csv")`.

Comment: Thnaks for you help! @F. Prive